Basement ventilation for small amount of Radon and some fresh air
We have had a couple tests over the years for radon and I feel like adding a bit of fresh air will only help the low levels we have. We have pretty good humidity control with a heat pump water heater removing moisture, so this should help the situation.
I have looked at some ERVs, which seem like an option but they can get expensive. I was thinking of just using it on its own away from my central heat pump system.
I also saw products like the EZ breathe basement vent system, but it almost seems too simple and will be a loss of energy.
We are in northern New England and need to consider the winter temps for something like this. Does anyone have some ideas on what might be a good for my application?
Edit: I was able to search more about HRV and ERVs, and the best for my environment at this time seems like an HRV. There were a lot of helpful comments on some products on SupplyHouse's website. It sounds like this model will be enough to move air in my conditioned basement.
https://www.supplyhouse.com/Fantech-SH704-SH-Series-Heat-Recovery-Ventilator-w-Fan-Shutdown-Defrost-4-Side-Ports-up-to-1400-Sq-Ft

I was able to search more about HRV and ERVs, and the best for my environment at this time seems like an HRV. There were a lot of helpful comments on some products on SupplyHouse's website. It sounds like this model will be enough to move air in my conditioned basement. https://www.supplyhouse.com/Fantech-SH704-SH-Series-Heat-Recovery-Ventilator-w-Fan-Shutdown-Defrost-4-Side-Ports-up-to-1400-Sq-Ft
